# Can't install third-party APK file

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, apk

I am a new programmer for Android, but I have been using eclipse for a year and a half now.  I am developing an Android Application for my school's health department to allow students to track certain health behaviors overtime.

I have completed the coding of the app and have successfully tested it on a virtual device.  The applications runs fine on the AVD.

However, the problem arises when I export the project as an Android application through eclipse.  I create the apk file using the debug.keystore and the androiddebugkey.  I create the apk file (which is about 115 kilobytes).  Next, I connect by phone (an LG Thrill) and open it via My Computer.  I drag and drop the apk file into the "downloads" folder in the phone.

I use a Market App called ASTRO to access the apk file in the downloads folder.  However, when I try to install it, I get the dreaded "There is a problem parsing the package" error.  I have had this problem for weeks now.

I have tried all sorts of solutions.  I have developed the app for the same Android level as the phone.  I have tried making my own keystore and exporting.  I have also tried making smaller apps (ie: HelloWorld) and installing them.  I keep getting the same error.

One thing that I noticed was that whenever I go to the apk file in the ASTRO Market app and click on the apk file and then "Open App Manager", I see that none of the apk file's settings (ie: Name, Size, details) are shown.  All the Marketplace apps I have in the folder have visible settings by my apps don't.

What might I be doing wrong?  Is it something with building the apk file?  Or am I uploading it onto my phone incorrectly?  Whatever it is, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried running it as an application from Eclipse, with your LG Thrill connected via USB and selected in the Devices view in Eclipse?

Comment: 6 years later and we don't have a solution, I don't think we'll ever know what the problem is and the whole question is offtopic, ask on [android.se]

Answer (score 5):

Go to: `Settings->Security->Device Administration` and make sure you have `Unknown Sources` enabled.

Comment: I tried to enable Unknown Sources under Device Administration.  However, I when I click on Device Administrators, I get a message saying "No available device administrators."  How do I add device administrators?

Comment: No need to edit Device Administrators (I get the same message in that option). Just enable unknown sources.

Comment: I already have Unknown Sources enabled.  I am still getting the error.

Comment: I found the error.  I had 'android:minSdkVersion="10"' when it should have been 'android:minSdkVersion="8"'.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your manifest file?  What is the required minimum version of Android that you need, and what is the version on the device you are installing it on?  Everytime I have run into this problem, it is because the device has less than the minimum required version of the operating system on it.

Comment: I am coding on Android 2.2 and my LG Thrill P925 is an Android version 2.2.2.

Comment: I found the error. I had 'android:minSdkVersion="10"' when it should have been 'android:minSdkVersion="8"'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Home-->Settings-->Application Settings-->Unknown Sources Click Checkbox on

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda old topic but it has just happened to me (Android 4.1.1). 
Solution: If you have wifi turned on, make sure you have internet access. I dealt with this problem and multiply requests to install application appeared.